# Modify single row data by clicking a button in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, button, event-handling, sqldatasource

I have a question about the GridView C#. I have create the following table by using GridView to do the update and confirm function.

```
|------------| ---- | ----- | ---------| -------- |
|    Tick    | Name | Phone |  Modify  | Confirm  |
|------------| ---- | ----- | ---------| -------- |
| (checkbox) | John | 1234  | (button) | (button) |
| (checkbox) | May  | 2234  | (button) | (button) |
| (checkbox) | Tim  | 3234  | (button) | (button) |
|------------| ---- | ----- | ---------| -------- |
```

The data of 'Name' and 'Phone' are retrieve from 'SqlDataSource' from an Access Database. (database name is 'DBInformation')

The 'Modify' and 'Confirm' button are to add a button to the 'TemplateField' of column.

The 'Tick' checkbox is to add a checkbox to the 'TemplateField' of column.

Is it possible to

1) click the update button of a row, then the user can modify the data in the GridView on that row. It means that the 'Name' and 'Phone' field will change to textbox and allows user to modify. (e.g. I click row 1 update button, I can modify John to AA and 1234 to 9999)

2) click the confirm button to store the updated information to my Access database
(e.g. I click row 1 confirm button, the the AA and 9999 are store to database)

I don't know how to do this as I don't know how to customer the eventhandler for each of the row or I should use another method to do this function? Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For feature 1:

You should try to find out information about ItemTemplates => EditItemTemplate & how Bind works. Use button with command Edit

For feature 2:

Set command for select button to update and handle event.

Here is events that are available for gridview. 
[GridView Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf8xwy0t.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can bind only one SQL Data Source to a grid view in C#. That way you are limited.

If you want to flexible, all your code has to be in backend C#. That means you will bind one query when you click on button and another query when you click another button, so yes it is possible.